# Светло-светло(-)сиреневый

Tags: орфография, дефис, сложные-прилагательные

Как пишется "светло-светло(-)сиреневый"? Нужен дефис в скобках?

Comment: Слегка сиреневый, бледно-сиреневый, светлый-светлый сиреневый.

Comment: @shampar Просьба оформлять подобные "советы" ответами. Иначе невозможно минус поставить :)

Comment: Можно поднять красный флаг. Тот же минус.

Answer (score 3):

Вот что пишет [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/134-def-19-20):

Через дефис пишутся сложные имена прилагательные образованные **из двух основ** и обозначающие оттенки цветов, например: *бледно-розовый, ярко-синий, темно-русый, черно-бурый, синевато-голубой, золотисто-желтый, пепельно-серый, бутылочно-зеленый, лимонно-желтый, изжелта-красный.*

Вот что пишет Розенталь ([§ 39. Сложные прилагательные](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49,2)):
11. Пишутся через дефис сложные прилагательные, обозначающие оттенки цветов.

И у него нет уточнения — про "две основы". Что же мешает использовать в сложном слове, описывающем особенный цвет, два дефиса? Ничего.
Самый известный такой цвет — серо-буро-малиновый.
У А. Солженицына:

> На Смотрителе был расстёгнутый пиджак — долгополый и охватистый, как бушлат, кой-где и подштопанный, а цвета того самого из присказки — серо-буро-малинового.

В Нацкорпусе нашлись вот такие цвета:

Он посмотрел на меня ― странно, без тени страха или злости, даже обиды не было в его раскосых **темно-темно-карих** глазах, лишь удивление и словно бы вина. [Ю. М. Нагибин. В те юные годы (1983)

Он и женился на ее славе, а не на ней ― пожилой, отяжелевшей, но еще красивой женщине с искусно окрашенными волосами ― в **темно-темно-красный** цвет. [Анатолий Мариенгоф. Мой век, мои друзья и подруги (1956-1960)]

[Оттенки сиреневого цвета](https://lookcolor.ru/populyarnye-ottenki/sirenevyj-cvet-chast-vtoraya/) — возможно, кто-то и увидит здесь светло-светло-сиреневый.

Comment: Дополню ещё одним примером: [цвет тюльпана](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=ChQmAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_wYLPoObqAhXMBhAIHcMCAmcQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg).

Comment: @grizzly Признательна за примеры и поддержку, Медведик. P. S. А что у Вас сегодня с настроением? Искры сыплются во все стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Так не говорят. А *светло-* или *тёмно-какой-то* всегда пишется через дефис. Поэтому, если так всё-таки сказать (написать), нужны будут оба дефиса.

Comment: *Так не говорят* — странно, я много раз слышал. Легко гуглится. [Например](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=VbIpAQAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%22&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ9aD7nObqAhXnh4sKHYbhDY04ChDoATAIegQIARAC).

Comment: Значит, действительно говорят. ;)